# Can I ground an amplifier on a bolt that touches the chassis or does my ground need to touch the chassis?

Tags: wiring, ground

I currently have my amplifier grounded like this but I need to turn up the gain to the max to hear my subwoofer.

Is this a good ground or does the ground connector ring actually need to touch the chassis? I'm talking about the one in the middle on the black plate with the 2 bolts.

[image: ground]

Answer (score 1):

That, as an earth or ground, should be sufficient as long as there is metal to metal contact, ie the paint is removed. Try testing a direct earth to the battery with a long cable, if there is no change then that is not your problem.

The problem for low sound level is most likely due to an input error (possible cable faulty) or an error on the settings for output level or trigger level.

Comment: I changed the RCA cables and even replaced my head unit. My amp runs at a gain for 0.2V signal while my head unit should output 3V+.

Comment: Did you replace the earth and test?

Comment: In general I like running amp grounds directly to the battery negative.  Costly in terms of wire, but tends to keep noise out of the amp.  It looks like you are using fine braided and twisted wire cable, which is great for noise rejection.  In any case, as long as the paint if off the black bracket, that grounding point should be sufficient.